# SQL View use field from view to calculate another value

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have such view:

```
create view resources_view as
select message.id                                                                                                 AS ID,
       message.id                                                                                                 AS SORT_ID,
       'MESSAGE'                                                                                                  AS TYPE,
       message.description                                                                                        AS PREVIEW,
       message.created_at                                                                                         AS CREATED_AT,
       message.modified_at                                                                                        AS MODIFIED_AT,
       user.nickname                                                                                              AS CREATOR,
       message.creator_id                                                                                         AS CREATOR_ID,
       IF(message.deleted = TRUE, 'DELETED', IF(reportNumberCountFunction(message.id, 'message') > 0, 'REPORTED',
                                                IF(message.verified_at IS NOT NULL, 'VERIFIED', 'NOT_VERIFIED'))) AS STATUS,
       userAssignee.nickname                                                                                      AS ASSIGNEE,
       message.assignee_id                                                                                        AS ASSIGNEE_ID,
       reportNumberCountFunction(message.id, 'message')                                           AS REPORT_NUMBERS
from message message
         join user user ON message.creator_id = user.id
         left join user userAssignee ON message.assignee_id = userAssignee.id
```

As you can see **reportNumberCountFunction** is used twice on same query. I didn't found anything useful so I need to ask question to experts. Is there a possibility to use this value from **REPORT_NUMBERS** or somehow store in some temporary variable this value so I won't call this function two times ? Im using newest MariaDB

Comment: The real question is: Even though you have it twice in here, is the database smart enough to know it only needs to run it once. That, I'm not sure of since mariadb optimization steps aren't as amazing as other RDBMSs. You could stick `messages` in a subquery and run the function in there once `...FROM (SELECT messages.*, reportNumberCountFunction(id)  reportNumberCount FROM messages) as msgs JOIN user ON msg.creator_id = user.id...` which would pretty much ensure it only runs it once.

Comment: You have tagged conflicting techologies, this SQL is not valid T-SQL I have removed the *tsql* tag.

Answer (score 0):

Text book use of a CROSS APPLY but don't think that's a thing in MariaDB.

Next best thing. Use a derived table with the function in once, then you can refer to the output by the alias in the outer query.